# Material-UI with reactjs: How to use or implement breadcrumbs

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Is there anyway I can use breadcrumbs using material-ui (that is based on reactjs)? Or even implement one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Breadcrumbs are coming to Material, keep an eye out for when https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/pull/14084 lands.

Edit, they are now in core:

https://material-ui.com/components/breadcrumbs/

Comment: Breadcrumbs are now in core: https://material-ui.com/components/breadcrumbs/

Answer (score 2):

I don't think Material-UI has a breadcrumb component, so you will need tp implement a custom React component yourself and use simple Text, the IconButton or FlatButton.

Here are some design ideas from Materialize:
http://demo.geekslabs.com/materialize-v1.0/ui-breadcrumbs.html

Answer (score 1):

I think the closest thing to breadcrumbs that you'll find is the Stepper Component. I'm sure after a good amount of time beating the proverbial head against it, one could figure out how to style the stepper to look like breadcrumbs.

http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/stepper

Answer (score 0):

Use [materialize.css](http://materializecss.com/breadcrumbs.html) framework. It has all type of components. check out there. and try it.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I checked it out. But I wanted to stick with material-ui since the project I am working on is already based  on it.

Comment: can you share the material-ui website

Comment: I have already tagged my question with material-ui, their website is: http://material-ui.com